# How to clear cache for NSURL on refresh in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, caching

Hello I have a code below which works fine with one exception, after Pull to Refresh it returns cached version of rss feed. 
For example if I use different URL or add additional query parameter for LoadRSSRefresh function it reloads new feed on the fly, but if I want to perform pull to refresh with same URL it serving cached version of it.

Thank you

```
import UIKit
class eventsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var myFeed : NSArray = []
var url: NSURL = NSURL()
var urlRefresh: NSURL = NSURL()
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.rowHeight = 70
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self


url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/?cat=6&feed=rss2")!
loadRss(url)


    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

    urlRefresh = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/?cat=6&feed=rss2")!
    loadRssRefresh(url)
 }

 func loadRss(data: NSURL) {


    var myParser : XmlParserManager = XmlParserManager.alloc().initWithURL(data) as XmlParserManager

    myFeed = myParser.feeds

    tableView.reloadData()


    println("load RSSURL01")

 }

func loadRssRefresh(data: NSURL) {


    var myParser : XmlParserManager = XmlParserManager.alloc().initWithURL(data) as XmlParserManager

    myFeed = myParser.feeds

    tableView.reloadData()

    println("load RSSURL02")
    self.refresher.endRefreshing()
   }

    func refresh(){
    loadRssRefresh(urlRefresh)
    println(urlRefresh)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the `NSURLRequest`, set the cache policy to `ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`.

In Swift

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy:
    NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```

In Objective C

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
      timeoutInterval:60.0];
```